# Strange syntax in ef

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, entity-framework-6

```
 var items = context.Items.Where(x => x.IsActive=true).ToList();
```

Why is correct syntax and working query?

Comment: You have to use same syntax which you would have used in `if` statement i.e. `if( obj.IsActive == true)`

Comment: What do you mean by `working` are you expecting this to throw and error?

Comment: Trying to compile that with `Items` being a `DBSet<>` yields `error CS0832: An expression tree may not contain an assignment operator`. (fx 4.5.2, vs 2013). The only way I get it compiling is with a `ToList` call prior to the `Where`, causing it to be unrelated to EF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very subtle bug in the code. The `Where` Func needs to return a `bool` to be valid, but you are setting the value, rather than comparing it, so there's nothing to return, yes?

### General Explanation

The code compiles because when you assign a value in c#, e.g. `x = 1` that expression is evaluated, and therefore returned, as the value which was assigned (`1`).

People sometimes use this to lazily instantiate a readonly property, e.g.

```
private Foo myFoo;

public Foo FooInstance
{
    // set myFoo to the existing instance or a new instance
    // and return the result of the "myFoo ?? new Foo()" expression
    get { return myFoo = myFoo ?? new Foo(); }
}
```

or assign the same value to multiple variables:

```
// set z to 1
// set y to result of "z = 1"
// set x to result of "y = z = 1"
x = y = z = 1;
```

### Your Scenario

So what you are doing for each entry in the list is set `IsActive` to `true` and return that same `true` from the function. So then you end up with a new List containing all entries, and all of them have been changed to Active.

If you were using a property in the `Where` which is not a `bool`, such as an `int`, you would get a compilation error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'.

See this as an example (https://dotnetfiddle.net/9S9NAV)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var foos = new List<Foo>()
        {
            new Foo(true, 1),
            new Foo(false, 2)
        };

        // works
        var actives = foos.Where(x => x.IsActive=true).ToList();
        // returns 2, not 1!
        Console.WriteLine(actives.Count);

        // compile error
        var ages = foos.Where(x => x.Age = 1).ToList();
    }
}

public class Foo {
    public Foo(bool active, int age)
    {
        this.IsActive = active;
        this.Age = age;
    }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is actually a scenario where "yoda conditions" would be excusable. `.Where(x => true == x.IsActive)` will compile, whereas `.Where(x => true = x.IsActive)` will not, since you can't assign `true`. It's very subtle, indeed. Of course, `.Where(x => x.IsActive)`, is of course better, but maybe OP *really* wants to be explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is working as your are assigning the value and not comparing value which is syntactically correct and hence it compiles and executes correctly. Note that = is used for assignment and == is used for comparison.

When you say:

```
var items = context.Items.Where(x => x.IsActive=true).ToList();
```

In this you are not comparing rather assigning the `true` value to `IsActive` which is fine for the compiler and hence you find it working.

Answer (score 1):

Why it is working?

I think works because 'x.IsActive = true' will always evaluate to true.  So it's not syntactically incorrect.

In other words the code is saying:

- Give me all Items
- Set IsActive to true for each Item
- Return all Items Where(x => x.IsActive)

So as all items are set to true it will return everything.

Comment: Seems wrong with a `Expression<Func<EntityType, bool>>` predicate, see [my comment on question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34946396/strange-syntax-in-ef#comment57625619_34946396).

Comment: Third point is wrong and misleading. `Where(x => x.IsActive=true)` (if in a compiling case) will return all items cause it evaluates to true even if IsActive was initially `false` and even if a concurent process set `IsActive` to false in between. It is not equivalent in its last step to `Where(x => x.IsActive)`, its last step (supposing the assignment and the return of value could be split at runtime execution) is equivalent to `Where(x => true)`.

Answer (score 0):

use `==` for checking condition

```
  var items = context.Items.Where(x => x.IsActive==true).ToList();
```

**Or**

```
  var items = context.Items.Where(x => x.IsActive).ToList();
```

Comment: i understand. i can use Where(x => x.IsActive).
But I dont understand why my example is working

Comment: what you mean by `not working` are you getting any error?? what is `context`